# JSF Navigation Rule to the page itself

Tags: jsf, navigation, jsf-2

How can I define a navigation rule from all view-ids from #{current.doLogout} to the same view-id?

Comment: Your heading and description to my knowledge varies.  While your heading states you need to be in the same page after you click the command button(Which is what @Balusc described), your description states what I described.  Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't define any or return `null` or `void` in action method, it will by default display the same page as where the form is been submitted.

```
public void doLogout() {
    // Logout.
}
```

This way you don't need to fiddle with navigation cases in `faces-config.xml`. *Are you by the way already aware of the new JSF 2.0 "implicit navigation" feature?*

Comment: Your answer varies with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener.  Can a return type of action method be void?

Comment: If I don't define the rule in the faces-config.xml, the commandLink will be disabled due to lack of any navigation-rule!!!

Comment: @mvg: Yes, it can. I didn't said anywhere that it **must** return a `String`. @ehsun: then the cause of your problem lies somewhere else. Once again, are you aware about the new implicit navigation rules in JSF 2.0 which makes the entire navigation rules obsolete?

Comment: Do you mean by implicit navigation, the returning the name of pages (facelets)?

Comment: In fact I have a command link which can be clicked from any page (facelet) and will call a method of a session scoped bean. and after that I want the user visit the same page but he has loged out and the content of the page may be different.

Comment: Just returning `null` or `void` ought to work. Don't forget to remove any navigation cases related to this which becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use wildcards to achieve this

Just call the logout method in action tag.  and just add this to your faces-config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
 <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
<from-outcome>welcome</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
<redirect/>
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```