# Is JSF navigation to same page without loosing state possible?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation

I'm trying to implement a composite that has a few buttons in it.

This component is aimed to be used in several contexts, so the navigation cases may be passed as parameters to the component but in some cases I would like to just refresh the view (by returning `null` or using a `void method`, as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5145004/691916)) - when I use this, the view is refreshed but the component stays open (it should close on action completion) - if a navigation case is used, the page reloads (the component is effectively closed) but all selection states are lost.

Is there any way to navigate to current page without loosing state, or even just hide the composite after the actions are run?

Note: view-scope.

Comment: You mean to say, even when you return `null` or `void`, all `@ViewScoped` beans are recreated?

Comment: I realized the question wasn't clear, I edited the question for better comprehension - thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: The phrase *"the component stays open"* is too vague and ambiguous. JSF components doesn't have anything like "open" and "closed". Don't you mean "rendered"?

Comment: Yes, I mean "rendered". Are suggesting some sort of `rendered` control of the whole component?

Comment: Why don't you just change the `rendered` condition responsible for showing the part back to `false` and include it in ajax update?

Comment: That would mean an explicit call to the `rendered` attribute (like `<util:mycomp rendered="#{bean.actionDone}" ... />`) every time I would like to call `mycomp`. Plus, that makes me control the rendering using a `boolean` property in the bean. If I have no other choice I'll do this but I was checking if there was another approach to this.

Comment: You mean you didn't already have one? How exactly are you "opening" it then? Just do the reverse way of that.